# Can't access XAML elements after calling InitializeComponent on BasePage class

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

**Edit:** Here's a gist of some of the codebehinds and what it reports out: https://gist.github.com/mattkenefick/5c4effdbad712eb1a42f6cf7207226a6

**Note:** The question is specific to what's happening in an InitializeComponent call and not to much else. Please read the question in its entirety.

I have a `MyPage->BasePage->ContentPage` structure. If `BasePage` executes `InitializeComponent()` then the XAML elements lose scope within `MyPage`.. meaning I can't call `MyPage.MyListView.ItemSource = xyz` without getting a NullReferenceException.

If the `InitializeComponent()` call only happens in `MyPage`, then everything works fine (meaning that it **doesn't** get called in `BasePage`)

This question is very specifically about understanding why the `BasePage.InitializeComponent()` call breaks the references to XAML elements like `x:MyListView`.

```
   Models
   Pages
     ├ BasePage.xaml
     |   ⤷ BasePage.xaml.cs
     └ MyPage.xaml
         ⤷ MyPage.xaml.cs
   Views
   App.xaml
     ⤷ App.xaml.cs
```

On my `MyPage.xaml` markup, I have various StackLayout elements, ListView, etc. It all exists within a `pages:BasePage.Content` tag, like so:

```
<!-- for s/o: MyPage.xaml -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<pages:BasePage
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:pages="clr-namespace:Namespace.Pages"
    xmlns:views="clr-namespace:Namespace.Views"
    x:Class="Namespace.Pages.MyPage">

    <pages:BasePage.Content>

        <ListView x:Name="ListViewView">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <StackLayout>
                            <Image Source="{Binding imageUrl}" />
                            <Label Text="{Binding formattedDayOfWeek}" />
                            <Label Text="{Binding formattedDate}" />
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>

    </pages:BasePage.Content>

</pages:BasePage>
```

Within my `MyPage.xaml.cs` class, the constructor executes the `InitializeComponent()` method.

Here's what the `BasePage.xaml` looks like:

```
<!-- for s/o: BasePage.xaml -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    x:Class="Namespace.Pages.BasePage"
    x:Name="_parent">

    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout x:Name="VerticalLayout" BackgroundColor="#f1f1f1">
            <ContentView
                x:Name="cv"
                x:FieldModifier="public"
                HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                Content="{Binding Path=ViewContent, Source={x:Reference _parent}}" />
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>

</ContentPage>
```

---

So to reiterate:

Within the `MyPage.xaml.cs`, I'm trying to call `ListViewView.ItemsSource = SomeDataModel` after an async fetch from a REST server.

If the extended `BasePage.xaml.cs` class calls `InitializeComponent()` in its constructor... I will get a NullReferenceException when setting the ItemsSource.

If the extended `BasePage.xaml.cs` class DOES NOT call `InitializeComponent()` in its constructor... The ItemsSource is correctly set and the list appears.

Can someone explain to me why the parent `InitializeComponent` call causes the NullReferences in the `MyPage` class?

Thanks!

Comment: if you have a [mcve] I'd try to replicate it for you

Answer (score 2):

By default, the variables that Xamarin generates from your XAML are `private`, so you can't access them in inherited classes.

[Field Modifers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/field-modifiers) allow you change that default behavior

```
<Label x:Name="publicLabel" x:FieldModifier="public" />
```

Comment: I thought that might be it, but it didn't seem to work. Here's a little gist about some of what happens: https://gist.github.com/mattkenefick/5c4effdbad712eb1a42f6cf7207226a6

Comment: I wouldn't expect an explicit FindByName to work with an inherited XAML page, but I would expect the auto-generated type to be available if you set the field modifier appropriately

Comment: if this is really important you should probably create an issue on the XF Github and let the team respond

Answer (score 0):

First, I assume what you said is true (haven't tried it myself).

If that is the case this happens because your XAML is not inheritable the way C# class is inheritable. So what you do by inhering the XAML page is that you inherit ONLY its C# code, not its XAML contents. Having that in mind, `InitializeComponent` shouldn't work.

Comment: I didn't say it wasn't reproducible, I said I'd *try* to reproduce if he provided a MCVE

Comment: Right, @Jason said he couldn't try because I didn't provide a complete example.. but aside from that, I think I understand what you're saying which is that I can extend/inherit throughout the code behind, but not the XAML itself.

So... if I wanted my top class to have functions and dynamic "ItemsSource" bindings.. and I wanted the extended class to have the same (but within its own XAML), then I'd have to duplicate the XAML into the top class in order to utilize the extended code behind?

Comment: @MattKenefick yes I would say so.

Comment: To add to my previous: Is there not a way to extend XAML+CodeBehind, so that I can have parent classes instantiate and interact with both XAML separately? Like... if my BasePage.xaml had a ListView and I wanted that handled within BasePage.xaml.cs. BUT I had MyPage.xaml that also had something like a ListView, and I wanted that separated, but extended in its own MyPage.xaml.cs. That can't be done? Or I just need to rethink my structure?

Comment: @MattKenefick I am not aware that it can be done. So probably it can’t but wait if someone has another opinion, sure.

Comment: So here's a little gist of what happens, just for a bit more clarification to others. https://gist.github.com/mattkenefick/5c4effdbad712eb1a42f6cf7207226a6